# How Do I Pass A Parameter From link_to To A Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Building a project with Rails 3.1

I would like to provide a link in a parent model's show page that passes the parent model's id to a child object controller's create method.

I'm guessing this will require a custom route, but have no idea how to build it.

Is this possible? Or would I be breaking a Rails convention?  I don't want to use a multiple model form if I can avoid it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass them in as arbitrary values:

```
link_to my_path(:extra_attribute => value, :foo => 'bar')
```

Comment: Great! In my case I used <%= link_to 'Add an entry for this course', new_entry_path(:course_id => @course.id) %> and added logic in the entries controller new method to check if params[:course_id].nil?.  Thanks for your help!